# Colored Picklist Values in VF Page

Tags: apex, javascript, visualforce

Got scenario where I need to display picklist values coming from a text field values (0,3,5,10…) and when the picklist values are displayed, it should be colored out based on less than 12 would be in green otherwise color it red.

[image]

The problem is…

1. Cannot use the Schema.DescribeFieldResult due to the source of the values is not a picklist value. Is it okay to split it in for-loop? What would be the problem and/or best to do this?
2. With the split, I’m able to get the values and colored it BUT when displayed I’m getting a blank space. What could be wrong in the code?
3. The color should retain when the value was picked. Help with the missing code.

CONTROLLER

public List getDiscountList() 
    {
        List discountList = new List();

```
    List<Product__c> familyDiscount = [SELECT Discount__c FROM Product__c where name =: businessInteraction.TH_Product_Family_Name__c];

    SelectOption option = new SelectOption('0', '<optgroup style="background:#FFFFFF;"></optgroup>');
    option.setEscapeItem(false);
    discountList.add(option);

    for(Product__c p: familyDiscount)
    {
        if(p.Discount__c != NULL)
        {
            string color;
            for(string discounts: pf.Discount__c.split(',',-1))
            {
                if(discounts <='12')
                {
                    color = 'Green';
                }else{
                    color = 'Red';
                }

                SelectOption entry = new SelectOption(discounts,'<option value="' + discounts + '" style="font-weight:bold;color:' + color + ';">' + discounts + '</option>');
                entry.setEscapeItem(false);
                discountList.add(entry);
            }
        }
    } 
    return discountList;
}
```

```js
VISUALFORCE PAGE

<apex:column>
      <apex:facet name="header">Discount %</apex:facet>    
      <apex:selectList id="Disc" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!results.Discount}" }">
      <apex:selectOptions rendered="{!allowDiscretionaryDiscountFlag}" value="{!DiscountList}"/>
      </apex:selectList
                                <script>
                                    var entries = document.getElementById("{!$Component.j_id0:form:discDetail:discSection:discountTabTable:1:Disc}").value;
                                    for(var i = entries.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
                                        if(entries.discountList[i].text == ""){
                                           entries.remove(i);
                                        }
                                    }
                                </script>

</apex:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use inline styles for this.  Instead use CSS.

And don't use JS to remove Options from the Select.  Use Apex code.

So the way to do it would be something along these lines:

Page:

```
<style type="text/css">
.low-discount {
  color: green;
}

.high-discount {
  color: red;
}
</style>

.....

<apex:selectList id="Disc" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!results.Discount}" }">
  <apex:repeat value="{!discounts}" var="discount">
    <option class="{!discount < 12 ? 'low-discount' : 'high-discount'}">
      {!discount}
    </option>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:selectList>
```

And write a controller method `getDiscounts` that returns a list of numbers that are the discount values.  Something like this:

```
public List<Integer> getDiscounts() {
  //  get data somehow into familyDiscount

  // use a set to make each value unique
  Set<Integer> retVal = new Set<Integer>();
  for (Product__c p: familyDiscount) {
    if (p.Discount__c != null) {
      for (String discount: pf.Discount__c.split(',')) {
        // I guess this is a check you need?
        if (discount != '') {
          // turn the String into an Integer and add it to the set
          retVal.add(Integer.valueOf(discount));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return new List<Integer>(retVal);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What data type is the field `Discount__c`?

When you have the if statement `if(discounts <='12')`, you are saying return true or false if the value in the discounts field is less than or equal to string '12' as you enclosed the number 12 in single quotation marks.

You would want 12 to be an integer, also the data type of the Discount__c field should be an integer as well.

Comment: Discount__c is a text field wherein the values are 0,2,5,10 and soon as discounts. That's why I use split on it.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I was try to say in my answer. You are evaluating if one string is lower or equal than another string. You cannot do that, you have to use numbers.

Answer (score 0):

@Mihai Neagoe is correct. The only problems is with conditional statement evaluation.

Remove your if statements 
                if(discounts <='12')
                {
                    color = 'Green';
                }else{
                    color = 'Red';
                }
This can be used instead to assign the color.

color = Integer.valueOf(discounts) <= 12 ? 'green' : 'red';

Answer (score 0):

I really wish this worked, but seems like repeat tag is not allowed under selectList. So the given code does compile but gives a runtime error :
"Select components should have at least one child component of type selectOption or selectOptions "

see for reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm?search_text=repeat
apex:repeat
An iteration component that allows you to output the contents of a collection according to a structure that you specify. The collection can include up to 1,000 items.

Note that if used within an  or  component, all content generated by a child  component is placed in a single  or  cell.

This component can't be used as a direct child of the following components: